# cut away the black frame of images using MatLab

Tags: image, matlab

For my master thesis I have to examine several similarly structured images with Matlab. I have already coded the actual evaluation. My problem is that the images have a black frame of different thickness. This will cause the evaluation to be falsified. So far I cut the border by hand. So I wanted to ask if someone could help me cut this frame using a Matlab code.

Below is an example picture,
[image]

I tried to solve this problem with the edge-plug in (https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) but it didn´t worked.

Maybe you can give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be using the edge detection as you have linked to in your question.

Rather, I would focus on reducing the dimensions of the image and analyzing the "reduced image". In the following code you can see an example of reducing the image into two representative lines, and analyzing the line to detect the specimen.

```
% Load the image.
Img = imread('pfi36.png');

% Level to pass for the "edge" detection.
lvl = 50;

% Add a buffer around the edges.
buf = 10;

% Reduce the Image to 1D along the x and y driections respectively.
lrData = mean(Img,1); 
tdData = mean(Img,2);

% Find the indices of the edges.
indL = find(lrData>lvl,1,'first');
indR = find(lrData>lvl,1,'last');
indB = find(tdData>lvl,1,'last');

% Show the Cropped image.
newImg = Img(1:(indB+buf),(indL-buf):(indR+buf));
imshow(newImg);
```